Cannot create In-app purchases in Google for the maximum amount
We ran into an issue recently where a customer reported being unable to create an in-app purchase for their application for $350. The error they were seeing when using our services was:
Price 'x' (micros) too high for region 'y' and currency 'z', Please set priceMicros to a value between 'a' and 'b'.
In this scenario, our customer was using USD to set up their In-app purchase, but it failed because the amount was outside of the currency range permitted.
Normally this error would be very self explanatory and we would tell the customer that the amount needs to be within the min and max listed values of $0.50 - $400 (source 1, source 2), but the amount they are attempting to was only $350.
Here are some screenshots from Google's Play Developer console for reference:



We kept dropping the price down to find a working value and it was right around $300. The second screenshot shows that the last remaining currency that was 'holding up' the IAP creation was South Korea as all other countries allows IAPs to be created when the amount dropped to around $325, but the conversion to the South Korean currency was causing the IAP creation to fail unless we dropped the amount to ~$300.
At the end of the day, the problem is that the exchange rate fluctuations from other currencies is causing IAP creation to fail and the only 2 workarounds we could find are to either:

Drop the amount in a specific locale / currency - this isn't feasible for us from an engineering side as the IAP creation never succeeds via our API calls so we would have no way of having people manually adjust those values after the fact.

Remove that country from the supported countries list so that the IAP will not be generated in that country - This is also not a viable option as some of our customers don't want to limit which country their app is running in.


Is there any recourse or solution for us to solve this issue? Or do we have to just wait for Google to fix it?
Note: I tried creating a ticket here, but there is no component I could find that seemed to match so I am resorting to bringing it up here as per their docs.

That billing template has two issues a) the price in KRW and b) multi-quantity checkout option.
a) USD does not matter here. You have to adjust the South Korean Won;
because KRW 590.000 is a) above KRW 450.000 and also b) roughly equals USD 446.21.
KRW 529.016 would equal USD 400, but only KRW 450.000 can be set, equaling USD 340.25.
Dropping KRW might not even be a loss, unless the app is actually localized to Korean.
KRW 450.000 seems to be the absolute limit of what can be charged in KRW.
See Changes to Google Play's billing requirements for developers serving users in South Korea:

From August 2, 2023, developers offering alternative billing to users in South Korea must use alternative billing APIs. To get started, see the following details and visit our alternative billing API integration guide.


This basically is a /rest/v3/monetization.subscriptions RegionalBasePlanConfig
(it requires OAuth scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher) ...
{
  "regionCode": string,
  "newSubscriberAvailability": boolean,
  "price": { object (Money) }
}

Where Money means:
{
  "currencyCode": string,
  "units": string,
  "nanos": integer
}

Since one can change subscription prices, one could automate regional price adjustments.
Just fill in eg. KR, KRW and "450000" and the API call might resolve the one error.

b) Play Console Help ~ When you create the product you can set it to be multi quantity enabled however there are some restrictions:

Multi-quantity checkout is not available in some countries/regions.
In most countries/regions where multi-quantity checkout is available, the SKU price threshold is around USD 100 / EUR 85. To allow multi-quantity checkout, you will need to adjust the price (before tax) to below the threshold in each country/region.


While handling multi-quantity purchases suggests, that you have a misconfiguration there:

Note: Multi-quantity is meant for consumable in-app products, products that can be purchased, consumed, and purchased again. Do not enable this feature for products that are not meant to be purchased repeatedly.

So one can't have multi-quantity checkout enabled, combined with a price too high, per SKU.

When there are billing limits, exchange rate fluctuations and today's exchange rate, the most suitable API method might be monetization.convertRegionPrices:

Calculates the region prices, using today's exchange rate and country-specific pricing patterns, based on the price in the request for a set of regions.

If required, there's also monetization.subscriptions.basePlans.migratePrices

Migrates subscribers from one or more legacy price cohorts to the current price.


Some great feedback in here, ty Martin.
Regarding adjusting the currency, it does sound like the convertRegionPrices api does what we need, so that is an option.
To your knowledge, are we able to just omit a country from the IAP creation and have our customer go back in and add support for it / adjust the value for that afterwards manually?

When not distributing to South Korea, the entry should be gone; and all the other entries shouldn't have multi-quantity checkout option, because the price is too high for that. One can get the current rates with that API, but has to use monetization.subscriptions to change the price.
